# Runing keras model VGG16, InceptionV3 always error with ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 8, 8, 5) are incompatible

Tags: machine-learning, keras, data-science, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I've been trying hundreds time, try to reshape X_train, y_train, whatever it takes, still return this error. I tried with own basic CNN model, it works perfectly, but with transfer learning models, always error. I'm sure the problem is from the input shape, but can't figure it out to fix it.
I appreciate for your help in advance.

Here's the input shape:
X_train.shape, y_train.shape

(994, 256, 256, 3), (994,)

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share a minimum reproducible code?

Comment: if you remove `validation_split` from your code, does it work?

Comment: @Ghanem Yes i did when I saw the error underline, unfortunately, that was not the case.

Comment: I found the issue, all i need is to add a flatern() layer, and it works. Thank you guys!